# python logger module is causing libraries to call their own logging functions

Tags: python, logging

My original intention was just to log the data which I was calling via

```
logger.debug(' testing ')
```

calls within my own code. This works.

However, after initializing a logger object at the top of the top of the .py file,
it seems that the loggers of one of the libraries which I am using is also calling their logger (requests http lib).

```
08/24 10:01:34 - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - connectionpool.py - 202 - Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.technicianonline.com
08/24 10:01:34 - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - connectionpool.py - 296 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
08/24 10:01:34 - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - connectionpool.py - 296 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
08/24 10:01:34 - root - DEBUG - finder.py - 47 - testing
```

I only want the root - DEBUG log because that's my own. However all of these requests logs are also being included. If I had to guess it's because python is a dynamic language and the variables are visible, but that does not make that much sense because requests probably initializes it's own logger.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Cause youre scooping up all the logs. Set the root logger higher or define the level you want to log requests manually

Comment: See [`logging.config`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) to learn how to configure the `logging` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a

```
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

which will restrict the output from all of `requests` to `WARNING` or above (you can set the level higher, of course, if you'd prefer).

The same approach applies for controlling the verbosity of the loggers of other libraries you might use.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer isn't really a practical solution.  You shouldn't have to explicitly babysit every logger instantiated by every library you use.  Using `logging.Filter` isn't really the best idea either, because the standard filter will suppress all unrecognized messages, but you probably still want higher level messages from your libraries.

The correct answer is to follow both suggestions in Greg's comment.  Set the root logger higher and use a different logger for your own messages which you can then manage:

```
In [1]: import logging
In [2]: logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
In [3]: l = logging.getLogger('myapp')
In [4]: l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
In [5]: l.debug('hello')
DEBUG:test:hello
In [6]: logging.getLogger('library').debug("you won't see me")
In [7]: logging.getLogger('library').critical("you need to see me")
CRITICAL:library:you need to see me
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`logging.Filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) which ignores messages from the child loggers.